# Execute a Jar-File that contains JavaCV on a Raspberry PI

Tags: opencv, jar, raspberry-pi, javacv

I wrote a Java project which is using JavaCV (a Java wrapper for OpenCV)
After that I created a runnable Jar-file. 
I am able to run this file on two different Windows Notebooks.

If i run a Jar-File which is not using OpenCV, I can run it on the Raspberry PI.
if I try to execute the Jar-file with my Raspberry PI B i get the following error:

**no jniopencv_core in java.library.path**

- I use OpenCV 2.4.9 and JavaCV 0.9
- All librarys are available for Windows and Linux
- Java 8 is installed

Has anyone an idea how to run it on a Raspberry PI?

Comment: ARM processor? We'd need to build the native libraries first: https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/#build-instructions And then you could contribute your builds for others to enjoy! :)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used JavaCV on Raspberry PI but I'm you might want to 1st check if your `-Djava.library.path` flag is pointing to the correct native JNI libraries when you launch the java application.

If this not the issue you might not have the JNI library compiled for the Raspberry PI archicture (linux armv6). You probably have it built for desktop architectures.

Another issue is speed since you don't have a whole lot of resources on the Raspberry PI.
I've done a few tests in Java last year with a model B(512MB RAM) and overclocked to 1GHz but was still pretty slow. Perhaps current versions of raspian might run Java faster than then, but I'm guessing c++ will still be faster. If this is the case, you can make use of some of the things from my [RPI-CV-Goodies](https://github.com/orgicus/RPI-CV-Goodies) repository like:

- [OpenCV 2.4.8](https://github.com/orgicus/RPI-CV-Goodies/releases) built for Raspberry PI
- [PiCapture](https://github.com/orgicus/PiCapture) - a simple c++ opencv cv::Mat grabber for the Raspberry Pi Camera Module
- [ofxCvPiCam](https://github.com/orgicus/ofxCvPiCam) - an [OpenFrameworks](http://openframeworks.cc/download) addon for the above Raspberrry Pi Camera Module cv::Mat grabber with examples

[image: PiCapture Pi Camera opencv wrapper]

[image: ofxCvPiCam Pi Camera opencv openframeworks demo 1]

[image: ofxCvPiCam Pi Camera opencv openframeworks demo 2]